# need to access array from one js to other

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following is my one js

```
var ruleField = [
{
    id: "T1",
      datastore: "",
      table: "SENSORS",
      columns: ["SNS_ID","HOST_ID","SESSION_ID"],
      tableHeaders: ["SNS ID","HOST ID","SESSION ID"]
}
];
```

in another js i need to access columns array in dropdown options

```
 <select name="child.KEY_NAME" ng-if="child.KEY_NAME != 'Host' && child.KEY_NAME != 'Sensor' && child.KEY_NAME != 'Operator' && child.KEY_NAME != 'Value'" class="form-control" ng-model="temp.condition[$index][child.KEY_NAME]"" ng-disabled="readonly" ng-change="selectedOption1(selectAction);displayActionParam()">
     <option ng-repeat="field in ruleField.columns track by $index" value= "{{ field }}" >{{ field }}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: ruleField is an array so you need to access it by an index ruleField[0].columns

Comment: You may need to assign `window.ruleField =`, or include it in a `$scope` depending on your context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the `var ruleField` to a `$scope` varaible for using in angular directives just add below lines to work.

```
 $scope.ruleField = angular.copy(ruleField);
```

Change your expression in ng-repeat to  `ng-repeat="field in ruleField[0].columns track by $index"`

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('Ctrl',function($scope,$filter){


var ruleField = [
{
    id: "T1",
      datastore: "",
      table: "SENSORS",
      columns: ["SNS_ID","HOST_ID","SESSION_ID"],
      tableHeaders: ["SNS ID","HOST ID","SESSION ID"]
}
];
  
  $scope.ruleField = angular.copy(ruleField);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<select name="child.KEY_NAME"  class="form-control" ng-model="temp.condition[$index][child.KEY_NAME]" ng-disabled="readonly" ng-change="selectedOption1(selectAction);displayActionParam()">
    <option ng-repeat="field in ruleField[0].columns track by $index" value= "{{ field }}" >{{ field }}</option>
    </select>
                                                                                       
                                                                                       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add your first JS file with the `<script>` tag **BEFORE** your angular code (directive, controller, etc) the `ruleField` vector should be accessable from any script, and as @[Adrian Brand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679126/adrian-brand) says, you have to access the array from its index, in this case `ruleField[0].columns`, once these things are done, you should be able to use it and manipulate it.